# How to print job output in the log file

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

I'm running daily tasks of deleting historical data as a SQL server jobs. How do I print how many rows were affected in each run?

Here's a step in the job I'm interested in (replaced the actual DB name with "Database_Name_Here")

```
Print CAST(GETDATE() as Datetime2 (3) )

DECLARE @Deleted_Rows_1 INT;
SET @Deleted_Rows_1 = 1;
WHILE (@Deleted_Rows_1 > 0)
  BEGIN
     BEGIN TRANSACTION
 delete top (1000) FROM [Database_Name_Here].[dbo].[SESSION_LOG]
 where start_timestamp < DATEADD(MONTH, -22, GETDATE())
SET @Deleted_Rows_1 = @@ROWCOUNT;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
   CHECKPOINT
END
```

If I run it from SSMS, I can see this in the messages:
(1020 row(s) affected)
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
 SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

at the end of your procedure/function.

After that

- Open Job using SSMS then go into the Job Step
- Click on Advanced
- Tick Log to Table
- Tick Include Step output in History

[image]

Comment: You need to be specific of where the “end” is for the OP since simply PRINT @@ROWCOUNT with reset @@ROWCOUNT

Comment: I would tend to create my own log table where I record this sort of thing. Easier than having to go though the Sql Agent logs.

Comment: thanks, @simonare. I'm logging to a flat file. I will try your solution tonight and update tomorrow